# How does one calculate the average time taken for arbitrary initial number of ants N to fall off this stick?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve the following problem: https://physics.montana.edu/avorontsov/teaching/problemoftheweek/documents/problem_Math004.pdf

I completely understand part (a)'s answer and how to get there. However, I am struggling to see what concepts / formula(s) they've used to get the probabilities in part (b)'s answer. Specifically I have no idea how they have begun to form the 'P(X)dx = ' section. Could someone please help me understand this solution? It's been a long time since I touched probability distributions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This problem can be done in a conceptually simpler way (in my opinion); and without calculus. But that doesn't necessarily help understand the printed solution in  your link.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm curious as to see how you would calculate the answer to part (b) without that calculus? If possible I'd rather understand a simpler method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first note that based on the solution given in the link for part b, the conditions changed from a stick of length $1$ meter (to stick of length $L$ ) and from a velocity of $1$ meter per minute (to a velocity of $v$). As these changes are not supported in the original problem, I will work with the original given length and velocity.

Second: I will use the observation in the original post that ants may as well go through each other as bounce off each other.

Since there are $N$ ants, there are $N+1$ subintervals along the stick (end of stick to first ant; first ant to second ant; etc). [By the way, I am assuming (unrealistically) that an ant has $0$ length.]  These spaces have a total length of $1$ (the stick is unit length). Therefore the average subinterval length is $\frac{1}{N+1}$. So the ant who has to travel farthest has to go on average a distance of $\frac{N}{N+1}$. At unit speed, this takes $\frac{N}{N+1}$ minutes.